# How to deal with long running operations in End-2-End testing?

Tags: end-to-end, testcafe, waits

We use TestCafé to perform E2E-tests for a rather large management portal. Due to certain dependencies, creating or updating a resource can take up to 30 minutes, which is why we implemented loops checking for those results.

To save time, not every single test but mostly every fixture creates its own resource and then the test operations are performed on the same resource one after the other. But, because of the waiting loops, execution time is increasing rapidly with every new feature - which is why we tried introducing TestCafé's built-in concurrency feature, which did not work because tests of one fixture are executed in parallel so either a test tries to access a resource that does not exist yet or several tests modify the same resource at the same time.

TestCafé Feature Requests exist to [add the possibility of assigning an order to tests](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2011) and to [add global setup/teardown methods](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/745), both of which would help solve our problem, but as of now neither is available. What other possibilities do we have to reduce execution time of our tests?

We do not have direct access to the system that is causing the long waits, we have to await a sync process after creating a resource.

Answer (score 1):

> We do not have direct access to the system that is causing the long
> waits

In the environments that you run your automated checks, you can stub out this system (e.g., using [MockServer](https://www.mock-server.com/) or [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/)), so its response will be under your control.

You can then check the integration between your system and the external one with [Pact](https://docs.pact.io/).

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but unfortunately because our goal is End-to-End tests, we do not want to mock any components, as we want to make sure they all actually work together correctly.

Comment: I think you are falling on the scam of Integrated Tests (https://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/permalink/integrated-tests-are-a-scam). If you want to verify if two components can work together, I suggest looking into contract tests (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ContractTest.html | https://docs.pact.io/)